# Нажатие кнопок по заданному интервалу

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, settimeout

У меня есть две кнопки, первая должна запускаться через 3 секунды, вторая через 1.5. Для этой цели я написал функцию

```
var start = setInterval(function(){ autoLoopSlider() }, 3000);

    function autoLoopSlider(button, time) {
        $(button).click();
        setTimeout(autoLoopSlider, time);
    }
    autoLoopSlider(".button_1", 3000);
    autoLoopSlider(".button_2", 1500);

    function myStopFunction() {
        clearInterval(start);
    }
```

Но почему-то она не срабатывает, подскажите в чём я ошибся и как исправить создавшуюся ситуацию

Comment: Ну т.к. в 1ой же строке ошибка будет - ты передаешь функцию без параметров и при вызове функции будет ругаться Jquery (button is undefined) и setTimeout (time is undefined). Второй момент [ссылка](http://javascript.ru/settimeout). setTimeout функция вызывается асинхронно через заданный период времени.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно что то такое:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".button1").click(function() {
    console.log("halo1");
  });
  $(".button2").click(function() {
    console.log("halo122");
  });

  function autoLoopSlider(button, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(button).click();
    }, time);
  };

  var intervall = setInterval(function() {
    autoLoopSlider(".button1", 3000);
    autoLoopSlider(".button2", 1500);
  }, 1000);
 // где то тут нужно очищать интервал, когда он тебе уже не нужен
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <input type="button" class="button1" value="but1">
  <input type="button" class="button2" value="but2">
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы функция запускалась бы заново после отработки, это нужно писать рекурсию?

Comment: добавьте просто `setInterval(function(){ autoLoopSlider(".button1", 3000);
  autoLoopSlider(".button2", 1500);},100);` вместо кода после функции autoLoopSlider. Тогда каждые 100 ms будет вызваться код, который будет вызывать ваши кнопки через 1500 и 3000 ms  соответсвенно. Однако я бы побоялся callbackHell ошибки. Поэтому где-то тут нужно очищать интервал после выполнения.